# Finding solutions to a symmetric divisibility condition $x\mid p(y),\;y\mid p(x)$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, divisibility, diophantine-equations

In general, are there strategies for finding all integers $x$ and $y$ such that $x \mid p(y)$ and $y \mid p(x)$ for some polynomial $p$ with integer coefficients? For example, could we find all integers $x$ and $y$ (WLOG let $x \leq y$) such that $x \mid 2y^2-2y+1$ and $y \mid 2x^2-2x+1$. I know there are nontrivial solutions for this example: $(1, 1)$, $(17, 109)$, and $(29, 125)$ all satisfy these conditions, although I can't prove that there are or aren't any more solutions than that. Trying to express these conditions in equation form (i.e. $2y^2-2y+1 = kx$, $2x^2-2x+1 = my$) and eliminating variables doesn't seem to get me very far.

Comment: If $p$ is quadratic and $xy\mid p(x)p(y)$ $\iff$ $x\mid p(y)$ and $y\mid p(x)$, it is helpful to rewrite it as $xy\mid p(x)p(y)$. (One example is $p(x)=x^2-1$.) After cancelling the $x^2y^2,x^2y,xy^2$ terms this gives a biquadratic in $x,y$ (with a parameter) which can, in theory, be solved (think of Pell's equation etc) for every value of the parameter. I think things will be much more complicated when $\deg p>2$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. If we let $p(x) = x^2-1$, then $p(x)\cdot p(y) = x^2y^2-x^2-y^2+1$. Then, with parameter $m$, we have the equation $x^2y^2-x^2-mxy-y^2+1 = 0$. I don't see what substitution to make in order to rewrite this in the form $u^2-nv^2-1 = 0$ (Pell's equation).

Comment: The $x^2y^2$ term can be absorbed in $m$.

Comment: True, if we let $m = xy$, then we get Pell's equation, but that removes a lot of the generality from the problem. Actually, in the case $m = xy$, there are no solutions (rather, the only solution is $(0, 1)$ or $(1, 0)$, which is extraneous, because a number generally can't be divisible by zero).

Comment: As an example of this, letting $m = xy$ throws away the solution $x = 2$, $y = 3$ (which comes from $m = 4$). Clearly, $2\mid 3^2-1 = 8$ and $3\mid 2^2-1 = 3$.

Comment: With $y<32768$ I find just one further solution, using a method also suitable for other polynomials. However, some would dismiss my work as nothing more than brute force, despite the code running in next to no time.

Would you like me to post an answer?

Comment: I'd like a proof of the existence of just these solutions or a description of a method for reliably finding others (probably a descent method of some sort). Realistically, $32768$ isn't that large of a number on an objective scale. If your code can find all solutions up to, say, $y\approx 10^{24}$, that would probably be a good start at formulating an educated guess as to how many total solutions there are, although it still wouldn't be a proof.

Comment: Solution with $y<32768$. $(x,y)=(3277,20785)$

Comment: Sorry, $y\approx 10^{24}$ greatly exceeds my capabilities, so I leave this as an unanswered question, in the hope that someone else has a brilliant insight. Clearly I use a decent method, with $y$ as the driving variable, for then I have finite $x$ values to check. I’ll post solutions if and when I find them. I can see that $x$ and $y$ are odd, but I strongly suspect both are $1mod4$; may I ask if you know this to be so?

Comment: On the other hand, there are still infinite $y$ to check. Even if solutions occur vanishingly often for large $(x, y)$, unless there can be proven to be a ceiling above which _no_ solutions exist, it's impossible to know whether you've found all of them by your method.

Comment: I agree absolutely, but perhaps more numerical solutions may inspire an analytical solution. Any thoughts on my $mod4$ question?

Solution with $y$ up to $299999$. $(x,y)=(21493, 266933)$

Comment: $(x,y)=(11321,480877)$

Comment: I assume my solutions are of no interest whatsoever.